# Spring oauth2 : Access any resource server endpoint without Authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I have a scenario where I want to allow user to access a particular endpoint at resource server(running at 8098) from client application (running at 8080) without authentication. When ever I am trying to access it without client authentication it gives error access is denied. But when I access the same endpoint after user logged-in it working.

I have following configuration at resource server:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        public ResourceServerConfiguration() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
             http
                .anonymous()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/requestdetails/view-all-details/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        }
}
```

basically I want to make this endpoint "/api/requestdetails/view-all-details/** unsecured. so user can access it without authentication.

Answer (score 4):

I did some changes in config method and now it's working.

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        public ResourceServerConfiguration() {
            super();
        }


        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
             http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/requestdetails/view-all-details/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()


        }
}
```